# Save contact info through website subscription form to different database

Tags: web8, audience-manager

I have a requirement in which all website(except one) should save user contacts details on the default audience subscription database which is the working behavior, but one website which get published from same CMS server and also hosted on same CD server on which all websites are hosted, should save contact details on different audience subscription database which is on another cloud server.

So here my question is that how and where configuration needs to change for that single website so that contact details get save on the different database not on the default/existing database.

Comment: is the bin folders for this website isolated from other websites? If yes, you can specify that in the bin\config folder of that website in the cd_storage-config - if this website does not have bin\config - you may copy-paste bin\config and bin\lib from deployer to it. This would only work if your this website is isolated from other websites

Comment: Yes all sites have their own bin folders, but all sites are now migrated to the new version of web8, hence there is no cd_storage.config file now in config folder for any websites.

Answer (score 3):

1. Identify the publication which is publishing the content to
   website,
2. Open cd_storage_conf.xml in the discovery configuration
   folder,
3. Bind the following ItemType differently for that publication

> ```
> <ItemTypes>
>     <Publication Id="">
>       <Item cached="true" typeMapping="AudienceManagerProfile" storageId="Alternate_profileDB"/>
>     </Publication>
> </ItemTypes>
> ```

Comment: P.S - AudienceManager service might have duplicate cd_storage_conf.xml, we might need to do the same there

Comment: Also, AudienceManager still requires the old Tridion style configuration files in the bin\config folder cd_audience_manager_conf.xml, Open and update the <DefaultPublicationId>72</DefaultPublicationId>

Comment: The Above bin\config is for the actual website

Comment: Just a note that DefaultPublicationId in your configuration file is used as a last resort. It is not needed if you have set up your Publication Mappings and topology correctly.